# show xAxes on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

This is a simple attempt to show labels after user click in one of bars: https://codepen.io/marcelo2605/pen/zNrGpE?editors=0010

```
ctx.on('click', function(evt){
    myChart.options.tooltips.enabled = true;
    myChart.options.scales.xAxes.display = true;
});
```

But nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the code a bit:

```
myChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].display = true;
```

That's because the properties of xAxes are store in one-element array that is an object. You can check it with `console.log`.

also you can see here: [Chart.js documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-chart-options)

Comment: You are correct. But you also need `myChart.update();` after that, in order to apply the new values to the chart.

Comment: Thanks folks! Fixed.

Comment: @xnakos Thank you for your addition